# global applied stylesheet link on debian box

Tags: python, html, css, hyperlink

Having some trouble identifying what is wrong with my link to an external CSS stylesheet...

I am using a debian box to host some things... including a file i am accessing page.py which is located in /var/www/cgi-bin. I need this page to link to a css file which currently has the pathname /var/www/styles.css.

Now I know I could link as:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="**../styles.css**" type="text/css">`

and the problem is solved but I would rather have a 'global' link, that I can use in other py files elsewhere in my filesystem and they will all point to /var/www/styles.css

The information I have searched suggests that

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="**/var/www/styles.css**" type="text/css">`

should work fine... but it doesn't.

I have tried multiple combinations of everything I know but it doesn't seem to link as I would expect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work fine. Could you explain why? My understanding of your code is that the styles.css is in my root directory, yet it isn't?

Comment: It's in the root of your Apache server, as determined by the DocumentRoot directive in your Apache configuration.

Comment: That is correct.... the Web root starts at /var/www/ so to access anything from your browser you specify the path from there.

Comment: Excellent, I understand now. Thank you Paul and Daniel.